# Ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS wont install any packages after reboot

Tags: networking, server, apt

I just installed Ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS on my old gaming pc to run a file server on.  I got it all installed on the PC and was able to apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and install samba, openssh-server, smbclient, cifs-utils, ntp and ntpdate. I set up `/etc/network/interfaces`:
 [image].

Everything looks right in there and I was still able to install packages and everything. Now, when I reboot the computer I try to install ddclient and I get:
 [image]

Now I get this no matter what I try to install or update or upgrade.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The screenshot of the `apt-get` output is hardly readable; Could you edit to add it as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` file you need to add your dns servers.  Try editing like below:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.10
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
```

Then run

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Try to ping

```
ping google.com
```

Comment: Ok so I tried that and 'sudo service networking restart' gave me this and 'ping google.com' did not work here is the output http://imgur.com/KZEYbjB . However when I restarted my server I was able to get packages to install again.  Seemed like it worked, very helpful thank you very much.  Any reason why 'sudo service networking restart' and 'ping google.com' did not work?

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working.... I am not sure why restarting the networking service did not work.  Good to know that a simple reboot fixed your issue.

Comment: I believe it is a bug http://askubuntu.com/questions/441619/how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot-over-ssh To restart the network in 14.04.1 you have to use `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`