# Ran /etc/init.d/networking restart, system won't start now

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I have just made some changes to `interfaces` file. I ran `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` as advised in the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine).

However, it resulted in an error and now when I try to connect to my server again, and it won't start. After doing some Googling, I found that `network-manager` should have been restarted instead.

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message that you are getting.

Comment: `Network error: connection timed out`. I also cannot ping the IP anymore. I do have access to the machine itself though through a VM. I tried `sudo ifdown ens160 && sudo ifup ens160` but no luck

Comment: First thing I would do is enter through the remote console and revert the changes you made to the interfaces file - it's likely those (rather than the fact that you restarted the service) that have broken things.

Comment: Tried doing that and ran `ifdown` and `ifup` but still nothing (though this might be because our IT guys gave me a wrong IP to use and had to change it to forward external IP to a correct IP). Just FYI: I had run the initial `networking restart` through SSH, not sure if that messed anything up?

Comment: You may need to restart both the networking service and network manager service to get back to the original config - for 16.04 (which uses systemd) the correct commands would be `systemctl restart networking.service` and `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` I think (note that the documentation you linked to doesn't appear to have been updated since 2009).

Comment: I ran `systemctl restart networking.service` but I don't believe I have NetworkManager as I get the following error: `Failed to start NetworkManager.service. Unit NetworkManager.service not found`. Unfortunately, still down after restarting `networking`.

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` show? And I would check with your IT guy that IP you're trying to use is correct

Comment: Mystery solved. I updated the `interfaces` and restarted the Ubuntu machine and all works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can fix this problem : [please view this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441619/how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot-over-ssh/958868#958868)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the Linux system using the remote console fixed the issue. Some network interfaces were not showing in `ifconfig -a` until the reboot.